# Error :: Método principal que no encontrado en clase

Tags: java, java-swing, javafx

Cuando ejecuto mi codigo, resivo este error

===**Error**====

```
 Error: Main method not found in class Invie, please define the main method as:
       public static void main(String[] args)
    or a JavaFX application class must extend javafx.application.Application
```

---

====**Main**====

```
public class Main {
    public static void main(String[] args) {

        Invie myMenu = new Invie();

        myMenu.Menu(showList);
  }
}
```

---

===**Método**===

```
public static void Menu (String showList) {
    String listMenu = "";

    JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Welcome to Invie App\n Creator: Wesly J. Hernandez");

    JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "This application is designed to help the user to have a better contror of his invention and buy.", "Purpose of the application", JOptionPane.INFORMATION_MESSAGE);

    String user = JOptionPane.showInputDialog(null, "User", "Login", JOptionPane.INFORMATION_MESSAGE);
    String passworld = JOptionPane.showInputDialog(null, "Password", "Login", JOptionPane.INFORMATION_MESSAGE);

    if ("adim".equals(user) && "myPassword".equals(passworld)) {
        JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Login successfuly", "Login", JOptionPane.INFORMATION_MESSAGE);
    }
    else {
        JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Login failed\n Please try agen", "Login", JOptionPane.INFORMATION_MESSAGE);
    }

    do {
        listMenu = JOptionPane.showInputDialog(null, "a. Add items\n b. Show items\n c. Remove items\n x. Exit", "Menu", JOptionPane.INFORMATION_MESSAGE);

        if (listMenu.equals ("a")) {
            JOptionPane.showInputDialog(null, "Upc Number of product:\n", "Addign items", JOptionPane.INFORMATION_MESSAGE);
            JOptionPane.showInputDialog(null, "Name of product:\n", "Addign items", JOptionPane.INFORMATION_MESSAGE);
            JOptionPane.showInputDialog(null, "Date of product:\n", "Addign items", JOptionPane.INFORMATION_MESSAGE);
            JOptionPane.showInputDialog(null, "Quantity Sold of product:\n", "Addign items", JOptionPane.INFORMATION_MESSAGE);
            JOptionPane.showInputDialog(null, "Items Prices of product:\n", "Addign items", JOptionPane.INFORMATION_MESSAGE);
        }
        else if (listMenu.equals ("b")) {
            JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Showing items");
            // String showingList = showList;
        }
        else if (listMenu.equals ("c")) {
            JOptionPane.showConfirmDialog(null,"Are you sure you want to delete a product? ", "Delet the items", JOptionPane.YES_NO_CANCEL_OPTION);
        }
        else if (listMenu.equals ("x")) {
            JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Thank you for user own system. See it soon!", "Exit!", JOptionPane.INFORMATION_MESSAGE);
            System.exit(0);
        }
        else {
            JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Please try agen.", "Error!", JOptionPane.ERROR_MESSAGE);
        }
    }while(!listMenu.equals("x"));
```

---

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Me parece que hay un mal entendido simplemente, en realidad estas usando JavaFX y mostraras unos elementos en la UI, por lo tanto tu clase debe extender de `Application` :

```
import javafx.application.Application;
...
...
public class Main extends Application {
```

de hecho es precisamente lo que menciona el mensaje de error:

```
 Error: Main method not found in class Invie, please define the main method as:
       public static void main(String[] args)
    or a JavaFX application class must extend javafx.application.Application
```

Revisa este ejemplo en donde puedes ver que la clase principal extiende de `Application` y tiene un método `main()`:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

---

*Recuerda, que usar [JavaFX](https://es.wikipedia.org/wiki/JavaFX) no es adecuado para crear una aplicación Android.

Comment: Muchas gracias pro tu ayuda. yo creo hace eso mismo pero la aplicación que estoy haciendo es mas una aplicación para escritorio.

Comment: Ok @WeslyHdz excelente!

Answer (score 0):

Este error ocure pues tu estas intentando ejecutar la clase ***Invie*** directamente por la linea de comandos. Lo correcto en su caso seria llamar a la classe ***Main***, pues es esta la que tiene el metodo main que buscas. Sigue el comando:

```
java Main
```